# how to get location at regular intervals using android api?

Tags: android, node.js, google-maps-api-3, socket.io

1. How do I set Android app to retrieve location of a device once a minute?
2. Do I need to use MongoDB and Node.JS stack instead of MySQL due to high load nature of a service? I.e. there will be high amount of simultaneous location requests from clients to a single server.

Comment: Modified question, now it should fit into site's policy.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB (NoSQL) is not a panacea for scaling. Your description of a problem looks like it could use the advantages of structured storage, thus SQL might be a good choice afterall.

> And I must use Node.js and socket.io with android

Up to you, but there is **no** *must* in using this technology stack.

---

```
    // Set the update interval to 1 minute
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(60000);
```

See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html).

Comment: These changes slow down to avoid sending to customers wanted to use node.js.Such as I check empty taxis.And every taxi's last location on my db and due to continuous queries should be sent to server.And I found a few empty taxi and sent requests until one accepts.this heavy traffic can only fix nodejs and mongodb for me..

Comment: Very likely, other options are also available. Caching the queries responses, so that cache server responds instead of database on same query - same result, might work just as good. Your choice, I just warn you of false assumption that switching database engine magically grants you infinite computing power.

Comment: What should I use when making such an application and application server What is your idea ?

Comment: Sadly this site policy is against technologies debates, as they often grow into flame wars. Nodejs and MongoDB are good choice, Nodejs and MySQL is a good choice as well for this purpose, as I said in the answer - taxi locations is sort-of relational data, MongoDB is non-relational database. I suggest you better start a new question stating your scaling problem, as well as what technologies you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the LocationRequest.setInterval to receive an location update each minute.

**Update interval**

Set by LocationRequest.setInterval(). This method sets the rate in milliseconds at which your app prefers to receive location updates. If no other apps are receiving updates from Location Services, your app will receive updates at this rate.

You can find a downloadable example at http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: thanks.Maybe I can learn that position has changed but I need to use nodejs and socketio.When swapping an empty taxi should transmit it to the server. from the server will be shown to all customers.